# Geocoder is automatically panning google map to the left

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am creating a page with a marker that stays fixed at the center of a map, even if the user pans/zoom the map. When the user clicks on the marker it shows the full address of the marker.

The problem is that the `infoWindow.setContent()` shows a string when I supply one, but pans the map to the left (and doesnt show the `infoWindow`) when I supply `results[0].formatted_address`.

The code below is the reverse geocoding I have. The alert function (which I have uncommented) shows the address correctly.

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': input}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    //alert(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                    infoWindow.open(map,marker);
               } else {
                    alert('No results found');
              }
            } else {
                  alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
      });
```

And my complete Javascript Code is:

```
    var map;
    var marker;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function initialize() {

        function setUpMap(){
            var mapOptions = {
                 zoom: 14,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.519422, 88.35741400000006),
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
                 removeMarker();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                setMarker();
            });
        }

        function removeMarker(){
             marker.setMap(null);
        }

        function setMarker(){
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: map.getCenter(),
                  map: map,
                  title:"Hello World!"
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                  var input = marker.getPosition();
                  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': input}, function(results, status) {
                       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                           if (results[0]) {
                                //alert(results[0].formatted_address);
                                infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                           } else {
                                alert('No results found');
                           }
                       } else {
                           alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                       }
                  });
             });
        }

       setUpMap();
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I think the problem is that, when the user clicks on the marker, somehow `setMarker()` gets called. I can't really find out where the problem is coming from. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Please supply a demo that exhibits the issue(for me there is no issue with the given code)

Comment: when you clicked on the marker, it didnt pan to the left?

Comment: the complete javascript i have already submitted in my question. The html is <div id="map_canvas"></div>

Comment: It didn't pan to anywhere, the infowindow opens but no panning.

Comment: Wait, when I change the size of the map it will pan. I'll take a look.

Comment: i have just created a jsfiddle acc and save my project there, kindly take a look there. cuz its panning to the left couple of times before showing the infowindow....http://jsfiddle.net/J4rey/rb45y16a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's forced by a interaction between the `center_changed`-handler and the autoPan of the infoWindow.

When you open a infoWindow the API by default tries  to pan the map to be able to show the infoWindow at the best position. But when this happens the center of the map changes, the marker will be removed(that's why you don't see the infowindow). You must set the `disableAutoPan`-option of the infoWindow to true.

Modified code:

```js
          function initialize() {

            function setUpMap() {
              var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 14,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.519422, 88.35741400000006),
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  disableAutoPan: true
                }),
                marker = setMarker(map, infoWindow);

              google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
                infoWindow.close();
                marker.setPosition(this.getCenter());
              });


            }



            function setMarker(map, infoWindow) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map,
                title: "Hello World!"
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                var input = marker.getPosition();
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                  'latLng': input
                }, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results)
                    if (results[0]) {
                      console.log(results[0].formatted_address)
                        //alert(results[0].formatted_address);
                      infoWindow.setOptions({
                        content: '<div style="xwidth:200px">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</div>'
                      });
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    } else {
                      alert('No results found');
                    }
                  } else {
                    alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                  }
                });
              });
              return marker;
            }

            setUpMap();
          }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: many thanks,...setting disableAutoPan worked its magic....one line caused so much problem...haha